# Login check on each page but with a pop up login window only

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, security, authentication

I am looking for a secure way to have a popup login window show up on the current page if a user clicks on a link to protected content.

I currrently have a login.php page with a form that is hidden and a javascript function that makes the form visible when it is called

then on the loading of the protected content page, I call this javascript function to show the login form.

On the form submit, the form calls a further php page called checklogin.php which has the mysql check and sets a session variable 'loggedin' if the user is found in the db.

The current problem is that on the checklogin page I set the session variable but I am now on that page and not the original page that called the login page.

How do I have the pop window show up and then check the status and then continue loading the page if logged in or throws the login pop up again with a login error message if not, or redirects back to the homepage if the protected content page is linked to without going throught he site menu.

I want to use the same login.php for the whole site which is spread around different folders on the server.

Comment: Maybe you can do this via AJAX? Post the login values to a PHP page and send back a response. If the values are correct you can reload the page?

Comment: I agree that I can do the  login check via ajax, but on the page load I check if the 'loggedin' session has been set and using an if statement, I call the login show javascript function if the session is not set or continue loading the page if it is set. So in the if statement, I can use ajax to check the db for the user but how will I continue to load the original page after the login check via ajax without having to reload the page again?

Comment: I don't think you really can do that, or at least not fool proof.

Comment: there are sites out there doing it everyday checkout moonfruit.com as one example

Comment: Where exactly on that website do they do that? I mean, use the popup and login, continue loading the page without refresh.

Comment: maybe I am wording this wrong or thinking about it in the wrong way but if you click on one of the templates a popup shows a image of the template and then there is a link that says 'click to build' this opens the login popup and if you login or register then it takes you through to the template

Comment: Hmm I really don't see anything else than that the page gets refresh / user is send to another page.#

Comment: so you think I should do the login check on the page before loading the protected content page?

Comment: I think that would be a lot safer.

Comment: but I am still at the original problem of being in the checklogin page. If I open the popup form on the link click, before loading the new page, I then go throught to checklogin.php. I now need to go off to the protected content which can be many pages spread over different folders. That means setting a session for the page that is being requested with the file structure in. Is there no other way of doing this securely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed in each page's php the login algorithm, returning the same page but with login window if login needed or content if already logged in.